# Why UTF-8 Unicode in address bar vs GET form is difference in C?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, cgi, fastcgi

I've developed a simple web page using C.

I will get the url address values and check them using strtok, strsep.

```
que=getenv("QUERY_STRING");
...
strcpy(val,strsep(&string,"="));
printf("%s<br>",val);
```

---

#### Browser Result when using `<form method="GET">`

**E.g:** When you type `۱` in an input field and press submit, it redirects to `http://localhost/api?identifier=%26%231777%3B`.

Output of `getenv("QUERY_STRING")` :

```
identifier=%26%231777%3B
```

[image: Address bar]
[image: Browser Output]

#### Trying with different values:

```
۱   => %26%231777%3B
۲   => %26%231778%3B
۳   => %26%231779%3B
۱۲۳ => %26%231777%3B%26%231778%3B%26%231779%3B
```

It can easily be fixed using a function in the **DecodeQueryStringC**.

This is written by Max Base.

https://github.com/BaseMax/DecodeQueryStringC

```
decodeUrl(val,val);
printf("Fix:%s<br>",val);
```

---

#### Browser result when manually typed in the address bar

I am using `Firefox 60.5.1esr (64-bit)` and `Chromium 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

**E.g:** When type ‍`?identifier=۱` at the end of the `http://localhost/api` :

It redirects to `http://localhost/api?identifier=%DB%B1` automatically by the browser.

Output of `getenv("QUERY_STRING")` :

```
identifier=%DB%B1
```

[image: Address bar]
[image: Browser Output]

#### Trying with different values:

```
۱   => %DB%B1
۲   => %DB%B2
۳   => %DB%B3
۱۲۳ => %DB%B1%DB%B2%DB%B3
```

---

I also want to support when the user manually modifies the URL (link).
Guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) string

```
%26%231779%3B
```

does not decode to `۱` but `&#1779;` which is a HTML entity and not UTF-8. You shouldn't be using `decodeHtmlEntities` but *just* the `decodeUrl`. Likewise there is some code that is doing the redirect that is doing too much.

Comment: I added some screenshots from the browser,You can see them.

Comment: When the user submit the form in the page, then the **encodeUrl** function can solve the problem.
But if the user manually changes the link and typing utf8 ... then I can not fix it.

Comment: You've not declared the *charset* of the response... which defaults to ISO 8859-1 and you get [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). Hint: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: It solved by `Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n`, Please change the answer text to confirm it.
Thankful.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know how about Arabic, in Hebrew there are different types of encoding. Like UTF8 and other ones,didn't fall into details but did you check that? I didn't anything with relevance to that in your post.